# jQuery Detect browser IE9 and below and throw up a modal to upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I want to be able to detect IE9 or less using jQuery (or if there's a better method?). If the browser version is IE9 or less I then want to load a modal with the option to upgrade to Chrome, FF etc.

I have read that $.browser doesn't work anymore, so just wondering what the best way is to achieve what I want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   /* Get browser */
   $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

   /* Detect Chrome */
   if($.browser.chrome){
      /* Do something for Chrome at this point */
      alert("You are using Chrome!");

      /* Finally, if it is Chrome then jQuery thinks it's 
       Safari so we have to tell it isn't */
       $.browser.safari = false;
  }

  /* Detect Safari */
  if($.browser.safari){
      /* Do something for Safari */
      alert("You are using Safari!");
  }

});
```

Comment: Use a conditional comment for IE9 only. That way you don't need to worry about sniffing an ugly user agent string.

Comment: you can refer to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Even though this question is old and already has an answer, I feel the need to suggest that you not use a modal to alert your users. Older browsers do not properly handle the displaying of a modal, so if a user is using IE5 for example, the alert may not appear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for detecting IE versions. Use conditional comments instead.

Why? Well think about why you want to target these old versions in the first place. It is probably because they don't support certain JS/CSS features that you need. So do you really want to maintain your own JS code that you are sure will run in these older versions? If you go that route then you need to start thinking about whether the detection code you write will work in IE6 or 5 or 4... painful!

Instead try the following:

1. Add your modal/banner element to your HTML.
2. In your main css file, hide this element using display: none. This ensures that recent versions of IE and non-IE browsers will not see it.
3. Create an IE only css or js file that will reveal this element.
4. Include this file inside conditional comments that target the IE versions that you want.

The example below uses a simple reveal using CSS but you can easily replace this with JS if you prefer. Just don't make it too complicated or it could easily break in early IE versions.

```
#index.html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css">
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ie-only">Go upgrade your browser!</div>
  </body>
</html>

#main.css
.ie-only { display: none }

#ie-only.css
.ie-only { display: block }
```

Here is a useful [conditional comments reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score 16):

```
var browser = {
        isIe: function () {
            return navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
        },
        navigator: navigator.appVersion,
        getVersion: function() {
            var version = 999; // we assume a sane browser
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
                // bah, IE again, lets downgrade version number
                version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
            return version;
        }
    };

if (browser.isIe() && browser.getVersion() <= 9) {

    console.log("You are currently using Internet Explorer" + browser.getVersion() + " or are viewing the site in Compatibility View, please upgrade for a better user experience.")
}
```

Comment: Note IE 11 no longer includes `MSIE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var isIE9OrBelow = function()
{
   return /MSIE\s/.test(navigator.userAgent) && parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]) < 10;
}
```

Comment: `navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]` is a string, not a number, e.g. : ` 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)`

Answer (score 0):

[$.browser()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is remove in [jquery version 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) use below code in your script,

```
(function($) {

    var matched, browser;

    // Use of jQuery.browser is frowned upon.
    // More details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser
    // jQuery.uaMatch maintained for back-compat
    jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
        ua = ua.toLowerCase();

        var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
            [];

        return {
            browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
            version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
        };
    };
    // Don't clobber any existing jQuery.browser in case it's different
    if ( !jQuery.browser ) {
        matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
        browser = {};

        if ( matched.browser ) {
            browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
            browser.version = matched.version;
        }

    // Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
        if ( browser.chrome ) {
            browser.webkit = true;
        } else if ( browser.webkit ) {
            browser.safari = true;
        }
        jQuery.browser = browser;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted from [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/check-ie-version/):

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9.") !== -1)
```

Comment: Only detects IE9. Does not detect lower IE versions too.